# Given $span(W)=W$, how am I going to show that $subset W$ of a vector space $V$ is a subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra

Can I just claim that since $span(W)=W$ and span is a set of linear combinations of subspaces, $W$ is a subspace. Should I elaborate more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The span of a set of vectors is always a subspace.

By definition it is the set of all linear combinations of vectors in the set, so it's closed under addition and scalar multiplication.

Comment: I can use this as a fact right?

Comment: Sure.  Another definition is as the smallest subspace containing the set.

Comment: The definition confuses me a little, how does set of all linear combinations of vectors lead to the fact that it's closed under addition and scalar multiplication?

Comment: The set of all linear combinations is the same as the set of all sums of scalar multiples of vectors in $W$.